# Why isn't my Scanner variable converting into a double with: System.out.println(inputR.nextDouble());?

Tags: java, casting, while-loop, operators, java.util.scanner

Okay so I can't seem to find my interest by multiplying inputP * inputR, assuming this is because my scanner variable inputR and inputP are still not converted to double variable even after using this method: System.out.println(inputR.nextDouble()); - What is the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {


    //This program will display the value of the principle for each of the next 5 years

     public static void main(String[] args) { 

Scanner inputR = new Scanner(System.in); Scanner inputP = new Scanner(System.in);
double years = 0;   

    System.out.println("Please enter the principle value for year one: ");

    System.out.println(inputP.nextDouble());


    System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate for year one: ");

    System.out.println(inputR.nextDouble());

    while (years < 5) {

    double interest;
    years = years + 1;

        interest = inputP * inputR;

        principle = inputP + interest; 

        System.out.println("Your principle after 5 years is: " + principle);

    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to multiply 2 scanners. That's not going to do well.. Try to store in double variables the inputs you got from your scanners and multiplity those variables.

Answer (score 3):

A `Scanner` variable cannot be "converted to a `double`". To a Java specialist, even thinking such a thought is alien. You may have a background in dynamic languages such as JavaScript, where this concept would make at least some sense.

What in fact happens is that the `nextDouble` method *returns a `double` value*, and you must capture that value into a `double` variable, or use it inline.

Another point: you must not use two `Scanners` on the same input stream. Use just one and call its `nextDouble` method as many times as you need, it will each time retrieve the next double parsed from the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet won't solve all of your problems but I feel it will set you on the right path.

```
    // This program will display the value of the principle for each of the
    // next 5 years

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double principle, interest;
    int year = 0;

    //System.out.println("Please enter the year value: ");
    //year = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the principle value: ");
    principle = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter the interest rate: ");
    interest = input.nextDouble();

    while (year < 5) {
        interest  = interest + interest;
        principle = principle + interest;
        year++;
    }

    System.out.println("Your principle after 5 years is: " + principle);
```